# Login using x509 certificate

Tags: php, apache, ssl, x509

I'm trying to make an authentication with digital signature stick ( its my first attempt, excuse if some questions might look dumb :) )

I added this to .htaccess

```
SSLVerifyClient optional_no_ca
SSLVerifyDepth  10
SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
```

If the user presents a correct certificate i get the certificate in $_SEREVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"]

```
$data = openssl_x509_parse ( $_SERVER["SSL_CLIENT_CERT"]);
```

If the client cancels the dialog to select a certificate, is there a way to ask him again for certificate when he reloads the page ? Right now i need to restart the browser to be asked again and might be an issue if he has other pages opened.

Thanks!